# How to get audio object from file_id in Telegram?

Tags: api, telegram

For a file uploaded to Telegram, I have a file_id and I can download it. But when the file is sent originally, there is an [audio object](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#audio) available that has more metadata than the file (for example, title, performer, etc.). Is there a way to get this information again by having just the file_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sendAudio](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#sendaudio) method to send the audio to a chat and the response will contain all the attached details.

Comment: This seems to be the only way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to get such information from the file_id only. No one knew what was contained in the file_id until recently when a couple of individual managed to 'crack' it. You can check what is in a file_id using [this](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto/commit/3728f03af34301a16a5f4f452caac10f48099628). So a file_id is just a representation of the location of a file on the Telegram servers which contains a little bit of information such as data center, location of file, a hashed checksum which further contains original uploader etc.